# Error when Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP Protocol

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM URL
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

> **Headers**
>
> 1. Content-Type : application/json
> 2. Authentication : key="hjgaj........."

Body:

Sending Data to FCM Server Like this

```
{
    "data" : {
                 "body" : "great match!",
                 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
                 "content_available" :"true",
                 "priority" : "high"
            } 
 }
```

Iam getting Responce Only

to

from FCM Server

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing the "to" parameter in your json. You should specify the recepient of the message. In the "to" parameter you can specify a device notification token or a topic.

Comment: In addition to what @dallas92 mentioned, the parameters `content_available` and `priority` should be in the same level as the `to` parameter. And `body` & `title` should be inside `notification` param. Refer to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) for a guide in the payload format.

Comment: ok i will try , thanks  :)